# FadeIn FadeOut with Loop

Tags: jquery, loops, fadein, fadeout

I want to loop the following code. I searched but I do not find a solution. Could somebody help me?

```
<script>


$(function(){
$('img#picture').fadeIn('slow');

setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('#test').fadeIn("slow"); 
 }, 2000 ); 

setTimeout(function(){ 
 $('#test').fadeOut("slow"); 
 }, 10000 ); 


})

</script>
```

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to loop the whole script. at first to fadein the images and then fadein and fadeout the divs time-delayed. when everything was run I want to loop. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for showing me the website, please try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('img#jana, img#katharina, img#kathrin').fadeIn('slow', function () {

        setTimeout(showNext, 2000);

        setInterval(showNext, 10000);

    });

    function showNext() {
        var target = $('#expertenbilder');

        if (target.find('#sprechblase_jana').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");

            setTimeout(function () {
                target.find('#sprechblase_katharina').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 2000);
        } else if (target.find('#sprechblase_katharina').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");

            setTimeout(function () {
                target.find('#sprechblase_kathrin').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 2000);
        } else if (target.find('#sprechblase_kathrin').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");

            setTimeout(function () {
                target.find('#sprechblase_jana').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            $('#sprechblase_jana').fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is unfortuenetely not working. The script is working but without looping. best regards

Comment: It should be working, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe I did not understand your question.

Comment: I want to loop the whole script. at first to fadein the images and then fadein and fadeout the divs time-delayed. when everything was run I want to loop. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can provide HTML then I could probably provide a more useful example.

Comment: Please see the edit again. I have not tested the code but I hope the logic is understandable.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not working. See on my homepage.

Comment: The very easy solution is: <script>

$(function(){
$('img#jana, img#katharina, img#kathrin').fadeIn('slow');

$(document).ready(function () {
function sprechblasen(){
        $('#sprechblase_jana').delay(2000).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800);
  $('#sprechblase_katharina').delay(7600).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800);
        $('#sprechblase_kathrin').delay(13200).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800, sprechblasen);
                                                                 //^callback function
}   
sprechblasen();
});
})
</script>

Comment: Sorry about that, I had incorrect syntax. `.is('visible')` should be `.is(':visible')`. I cannot view your site anymore but I trust you have it working the way you need now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

use `setInterval`

```
var t=setInterval(function(){

$('img#picture').fadeIn('slow');

setTimeout(function(){ 
 $('#test').fadeIn("slow"); 
}, 2000 ); 

setTimeout(function(){ 

  $('#test').fadeOut("slow"); 
}, 10000 ); 

},3000)  //3000 is just an example, set suitable interval to allow effect to run smoothly 


window.clearInterval(t)  //to stop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunetely it is not working. when I only write setInterval without "var t=" it is working but not the first passage. it works then only from the second passage. best regards